# How to start/trigger a job when a new version of deployment is released (image updated) on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, argocd

I have two environments (clusters): Production and Staging with two independent databases. They are both deployed on Kubernetes and production doesn't have a fixed schedule for new deployments but it happens on a weekly basis (roughly).

I would like to sync the production database with the staging database every time that a new release is deployed to production (kubernetes deployment is updated with new image).

Is there a way that I can set a job/cronjob to be triggered everytime this even happen?

The deployments are done using ArgoCD to pull the changes in the deployment manifest from a github repository.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this functionality is inherent to `kubernetes`; you are asking about something custom that can be implemented in a variety of ways (depending on your tool stack)

e.g.

if you are using `helm` to install to Production, you can use a `post-install` [hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) that triggers a `Job` that does what you want.

Perhaps ArgoCD has some post-install functionality that can also create a `Job` resource doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use a tool like [Kyverno](https://kyverno.io/docs/writing-policies/generate/) and write a policy to generate a K8s job upon any resource created in K8s.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the case what Argo Events is for.

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/

There are many ways to implement this, but it depends on your exact situation how it’s best for you.

Eg. if you can use a Git tag event’s webhook you could go with an HTTP trigger to initiate a Job or Argo Workflow.